# Unable to get public IP for EKS cluster service

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I have a working Kubernetes Cluster on AWS EKS.
I've deployed :

- aws-load-balancer-controller
- ingress-nginx

I want a single load balancer, and multiple ingresses behind.
As a sample service, i've deployed a basic grafana pods, which works with port-forward

I want to expose it on internet, so I enabled ingress. But I can't get a public IP with the load balancer. It only gives me private IPs

Here's terraform code releated to these files

```yaml
# aws-load-balancer-controller
clusterName: ${cluster_name}
    
serviceAccount:
    create: true

vpcId: ${vpc_id}

ingressCLass: nginx
```

```yaml
# ingress-nginx
controller:
    service:
        annotations:
            alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: default-ingress
            alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
            alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
            alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: subnet-public1,subnet-public2,subnet-public3
            #alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /healthz

defaultBackend:
    enabled: true
```

Can you please help me spotting my error ?